# Remove the Id from the route definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is my routes:

```
PUT    /welcome/:id(.:format)      welcome#update
```

I want remove the :id from the route definition.

in other words, I want to use the update function without sending an id.

so in my routes.rb, I tried to define:

```
resources :welcome
match '/welcome/:id' => 'welcome#update', :via => :put
```

then I ran `rake routes`, but nothing has happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really want to use a put request? I think you should use the a custom action to handle this. But in case you want to override the default routing, you can do it this way

```
match 'welcome/' => 'welcome#update', :via => 'put'
resources :welcome, :except => [:update]
```

Answer (score 2):

use `put '/welcome' => 'welcome#update'`before `resources :welcome` so it takes precedence

UPDATE: formatting

```
put '/welcome' => 'welcome#update'
resources :welcome
```

Comment: I wrote:
put '/welcome' => 'welcome#update'
resources :welcome

but it doesn't work..

Comment: updated my answer with better formatting.  be reminded that when you try to send to `/welcome/anything_here`, it will not match the first route